# How to save sql query result to excel?

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, export-to-excel

How to save the sql query result from SQL Server 2008 R2 to Microsoft Excel 2008?

Comment: SQL Server has an export wizard that supports Excel with more details [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209(v=sql.100).aspx). If it helps, let me know and I'll put it as an answer.

Comment: You can use the "export data" task on a database to save either a table or query results as an excel file. https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-import-and-export-sql-server-data-to-an-excel-file/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The manual way, if your in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), is to just highlight the rows and columns and paste it in Excel or you can right-click and save as a CSV file and open it in Excel.

To bring over the headers, you want to:

1. Click on the **Tools** menu option.
2. Click on **Options** -> **Query Results** -> **Sql Server** -> **Results to Grid**
3. Tick **Include Column Headers when Copying or Saving the Results**

Then do your copy and paste.